# Find a symmetric matrix in python

Tags: python

I have a list from A to Z. `[A, B, C, D, ...., Z]`

I should get a 26x26 symmetric matrix where the diagonal is equal to zero.

I am using a random number generator to fill the upper half of the matrix. Later I want to copy the same upper half of the matrix to the lower half of the matrix.

Is there an easy way of doing it in python? (with fewer iterations)?

Comment: What does the matrix have to do with your list?

Comment: Can you share the code you have so far?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ I want to iterate through the list to create the random number. E.g., for A, I iterate over all 26 characters.

Comment: The relation between the list and the matrix is still not clear, despite your last comment. Do you mean that each non-diagonal entry of the matrix equals one of the values in the list? Also, what do you mean by "with fewer iterations"? Do you mean you want one line of code as in a comprehension, or to iterate over the matrix only once, or something else? Finally, if you show your own code so far that could clear up multiple issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can first make the upper random matrix like this:

```
import random
grid = []
for i in range(26):
 grid.append([0]*(i+1)+random.sample(xrange(100), 25-i)) #this creates the upper triangular matrix with random numbers (upto 100) only. The diagonal and the lower triangular matrix has items = 0
```

Then in order to make the symmetric matrix, just do this:

```
 for i in range(1, 26):
  for j in range(0,i):
   grid[i][j]=grid[j][i] #this copies the element "opposite" to that index w.r.t the diagonal in order to make a symmetric matrix.
```

Note: The diagonal elements are still left to zero.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Please do consider an upvote if you found the answer useful. :)

Comment: Excellent! Good answer :)

Comment: Your answer would be even better if you replaced `([0 for j in range(i+1)]` with `[0] * (i+1)`.

Comment: @RoryDaulton I tried that. For some reason it didn't work. :/

Comment: That's strange. Your code with the line `grid.append([0] * (i+1) + random.sample(range(100), 25-i))` in my Python 3.6.2 (that's why it's `range` rather than `xrange`) works fine and gives a good answer.

Comment: I think I must have typed something wrong while coding it. Otherwise, there's no other explanation. I'll edit it then.